# C#: How to copy excel cell range and chart data to power point slides

Tags: c#, excel, powerpoint, excel-interop

I have data and chart in Excel Worksheet which I need to copy at run time from Excel to power point slides.

I have a code which is working fine but the code only can copy chart data to excel sheet not range data.

Please see the scree shot of my Excel. So anyone has an idea how data is there in my work sheet which i need to copy to PowerPoint slide programmatically.
[image]

Here is code which I am using to copy range data and chart data to PowerPoint dynamically.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pptNS.ApplicationClass powerpointApplication = null;
    pptNS.Presentation pptPresentation = null;
    pptNS.Slide pptSlide = null;
    pptNS.ShapeRange shapeRange = null;

    xlNS.ApplicationClass excelApplication = null;
    xlNS.Workbook excelWorkBook = null;
    xlNS.Worksheet targetSheet = null;
    xlNS.ChartObjects chartObjects = null;
    xlNS.ChartObject existingChartObject = null;
    xlNS.Range destRange = null;

    string paramPresentationPath = @"D:\test\Chart Slide.pptx";
    string paramWorkbookPath = @"D:\test\MyExcelData.xlsx";
    object paramMissing = Type.Missing;


    try
    {
        // Create an instance of PowerPoint.
        powerpointApplication = new pptNS.ApplicationClass();

        // Create an instance Excel.          
        excelApplication = new xlNS.ApplicationClass();

        // Open the Excel workbook containing the worksheet with the chart
        // data.
        excelWorkBook = excelApplication.Workbooks.Open(paramWorkbookPath,
                        paramMissing, paramMissing, paramMissing,
                        paramMissing, paramMissing, paramMissing,
                        paramMissing, paramMissing, paramMissing,
                        paramMissing, paramMissing, paramMissing,
                        paramMissing, paramMissing);

        // Get the worksheet that contains the chart.
        targetSheet =
            (xlNS.Worksheet)(excelWorkBook.Worksheets["Spain"]);

        // Get the ChartObjects collection for the sheet.
        chartObjects =
            (xlNS.ChartObjects)(targetSheet.ChartObjects(paramMissing));



        // Create a PowerPoint presentation.
        pptPresentation = powerpointApplication.Presentations.Add(
                            Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue);

        // Add a blank slide to the presentation.
        pptSlide =
            pptPresentation.Slides.Add(1, pptNS.PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutBlank);

        // capture range
        //var writeRange = targetSheet.Range["A1:B15"];
        destRange = targetSheet.get_Range("A1:B15");
        //copy range
        destRange.Copy();

        // Paste the chart into the PowerPoint presentation.
        shapeRange = pptSlide.Shapes.Paste();


        // Position the chart on the slide.
        shapeRange.Left = 60;
        shapeRange.Top = 100;

        // Get or capture the chart to copy.
        existingChartObject =(xlNS.ChartObject)(chartObjects.Item(1));


        // Copy the chart from the Excel worksheet to the clipboard.
        existingChartObject.Copy();

        // Paste the chart into the PowerPoint presentation.
        shapeRange = pptSlide.Shapes.Paste();
        //Position the chart on the slide.
        shapeRange.Left = 90;
        @shapeRange.Top = 100;

        // Save the presentation.
        pptPresentation.SaveAs(paramPresentationPath,
                        pptNS.PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsOpenXMLPresentation,
                        Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        // Release the PowerPoint slide object.
        shapeRange = null;
        pptSlide = null;

        // Close and release the Presentation object.
        if (pptPresentation != null)
        {
            pptPresentation.Close();
            pptPresentation = null;
        }

        // Quit PowerPoint and release the ApplicationClass object.
        if (powerpointApplication != null)
        {
            powerpointApplication.Quit();
            powerpointApplication = null;
        }

        // Release the Excel objects.
        targetSheet = null;
        chartObjects = null;
        existingChartObject = null;

        // Close and release the Excel Workbook object.
        if (excelWorkBook != null)
        {
            excelWorkBook.Close(false, paramMissing, paramMissing);
            excelWorkBook = null;
        }

        // Quit Excel and release the ApplicationClass object.
        if (excelApplication != null)
        {
            excelApplication.Quit();
            excelApplication = null;
        }

        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

    }
}
```

Please see my code and let me know what to rectify in my code as a result cell range and chart both i can copy to power point slides.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it's as simple as *copy-paste*.  You'll probably need to create a table in the PowerPoint slide first and set the table values to the `Value` of the `Range` into the table.  I'm **not** familiar with the PowerPoint interop, but it would probably look something like:

```
var table = pptSlide.Shapes.AddTable();
destRange = targetSheet.get_Range("A1:B15");
for (int i = 1; i <= destRange.Rows; i++) 
{ 
    for (int j = 1; j <= destRange.Columns; j++) 
    {
        table.Table.Cell(i, j).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text =destRange[i, j].Text;
    } 
}
```

Comment: how to position table in slide by specifying left and top....any hint. i will test your code and let you know. thanks

Comment: @Mou Sorry, I'm not familiar with the PowerPoint libraries.  Try `pptSlide.Shapes.AddTable()` seen [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff745319.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: i do not know from where you got the code to populate table but when i paste your code it is not working. i checked that i have to populate table cell in for loop which is not my intention.

Comment: http://www.made4dotnet.com/tabid/141/aid/16/Insert-table-into-Office-Powerpoint-programmatically-in-.net.aspx   just see how people populate table in loop